# How to use GitLab CI in combination with a JUnit Rule that launches Docker containers?

Tags: docker, junit, gitlab

I have a set of integration tests that rely on a postgres database being available. In order for the tests to be independent, I am using [this](https://github.com/tdomzal/junit-docker-rule) project to start a postgres docker container before the tests:

```java
@Rule
DockerRule postgresDockerRule = DockerRule
            .builder()
            .imageName("postgres:9")
            .expose(databaseConfig.port().toString(), "5432")
            .env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", databaseConfig.password())
            .waitForMessage("PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.", 60)
            .keepContainer(false)
            .build();
```

This works fine locally. The rule starts up the container, the tests are run and after the tests, the container is deleted.

However, I am having troubles getting these tests to run on `gitlab.com`.

The tests always fail with the following exception (this is the end of a longer stacktrace):

```java
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.doConnect(UnixSocketChannel.java:94)
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.connect(UnixSocketChannel.java:102)
at com.spotify.docker.client.ApacheUnixSocket.connect(ApacheUnixSocket.java:73)
at com.spotify.docker.client.UnixConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(UnixConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
... 21 more
```

The project providing the `DockerRule` uses the [spotify docker client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) to connect to the remote API of the docker daemon. (That is why it throws an IOException stating "No such file or directory" - it cannot find the socket.)

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_rest-api:
  image: openjdk:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build -Dorg.gradle.parallel=true
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - 'rest-api/build/distributions/*.zip'
      - '*/build/reports/*'

deploy_on_development:
  image: governmentpaas/cf-cli
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - cf api ...
    - cf auth ...
    - cf target -o XXX -s development
  script:
    - cf push ....
  only:
    - master
```

What I would like to achieve is:

- Integration tests are run locally and during the CI process
- Integration tests connect to a real database
- No difference between local and CI test configuration

I thought about providing the postgres database as a service during the CI process using the `services` section of `.gitlab-ci.yml`. But that would mean that I have to manually start up a postgres database before I can run my integration tests locally. What I liked about the junit rule approach was that I could simply run my integration tests like any other tests by just having docker running in the background.

I would be nice if someone can come up with a solution that allows me to connect to a docker instance during the CI process but I am also happy about ideas on how to change my overall setup of integration testing in order for this to work.

Comment: It sounds like you need Docker running on your CI instance.

Comment: I am using the hosted gitlab instance on gitlab.com, so I cannot really modify the underlying system. The question is, how do I get docker running on the CI system?

Comment: Looking at description of [docker at gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html), looks like it does not give you access to docker engine. Instead it allows to define docker containers and will start them for you before running your test cases. Spotify docker client executes docker commands on available docker engine so I think it is not possible to make it work in this case. I'm the author of mentioned [junit-docker-plugin](https://github.com/tdomzal/junit-docker-rule) and I use [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) for CI because it gives access to docker engine.